# How to determine the shape/size of .npz file

Tags: python, numpy, size, google-colaboratory, shapes

I have a file with .npz extension. How can I determine its shape.
I loaded it on colab with this code

```
import numpy as np 
file=np.load(path/to/.npz)
```

I am unable to determine its shape

Comment: Have you read the `savez` docs?  Your `file` does not have a `shape`.  It's a `dict` object (with `keys`) used to access the arrays in the `zip` archive.

Comment: Normally we load `npy` arrays, and check their shape.

Comment: my file is a image features file. It worked by the answer given below. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generating Sample `.npz` file

```
import numpy as np
import zipfile


x = np.arange(10)
y = np.sin(x)

np.savez("out.npz", x, y)
```

```
def npz_headers(npz):
    """
    Takes a path to an .npz file, which is a Zip archive of .npy files.
    Generates a sequence of (name, shape, np.dtype).
    """
    with zipfile.ZipFile(npz) as archive:
        for name in archive.namelist():
            if not name.endswith('.npy'):
                continue

            npy = archive.open(name)
            version = np.lib.format.read_magic(npy)
            shape, fortran, dtype = np.lib.format._read_array_header(npy, version)
            yield name[:-4], shape, dtype
```

```
print(list(npz_headers("out.npz")))
```

Calling the above function, it returns the below output

```
[('arr_0', (10,), dtype('int64')), ('arr_1', (10,), dtype('float64'))]
```

Comment: when I call this function, it doesn't display anything

"npz_headers(path/to/.npz)"

even after using print command it displays
"<generator object npz_headers at 0x7f2161c3ead0>
"

Comment: You should explain what's going on.  I suspect the OP is too new to understand where that code is from, and how it relates to actually load the arrays.

Comment: Calling the function with "list" worked. Thank you @Pluviophile

Comment: Glad, that helped

Comment: Thanks! I wrapped this function in a small bash utility for quickly reading npz files: https://github.com/hkariti/npzcat

Answer (score 1):

You can simply iterate through each element and query its shape and other info.

```
# create your file
d = np.arange(10)
e = np.arange(20)
np.savez("mat",x = d, y = e)

#load it
data = np.load("mat.npz")

for key in data.keys():
    print("variable name:", key          , end="  ")
    print("type: "+ str(data[key].dtype) , end="  ")
    print("shape:"+ str(data[key].shape))
```

output:

```
variable name: x  type: int32  shape:(10,)
variable name: y  type: int32  shape:(20,)
```